# php cURL invalid sessionID

Tags: php, session, curl

I develop php application that makes POST request to api server with cURL.  Before coding ,I tested my request with POSTMAN(Chorme Extension). I made 2 requests, first login second getSomeData.

https://serverip/ismserver/json/authentication

Post Data

```
{
  "username":"myName",
  "password":"myPassword",
  "domain":"domain"
}
```

https://serverip/ismserver/json/devicetemplate/getDeviceTemplates

Server keeps my session and second request works.
Post Data

```
{
  "templateRef":{
    "refUid":"bc2929cc-5825-4948-8165-7f3fa8fea561",
    "refName":"Sample Template",
    "refObjectType":"vs_deviceTemplate",
    "refVsomUid":"daf6f543-1841-4719-ab67-ff50ca8a7387"
  }
}
```

This is works fine with Postman.

I start to write php code, this time it returns

```
{"status":{"errorType":"FAILURE","errorMsg":"Operation failed: SessionId is missing in the request header","errorReason":"SessionId is missing in the request header","errorReasonCode":"sessionid_not_in_header"}}
```

Also it doesnt work on RESTCLIENT(Mozilla Firefox Extenision)

My Code is below

```
 //---- First Login --- //
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $server."/ismserver/json/authentication/login",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST =>false,
      CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n  \"username\":\"".$username."\",\r\n  \"password\":\"".$password."\"\r\n}",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
      ),
    ));
    //echo $str; //test string syntax
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $content, $m);
parse_str($m[1], $cookies);
$cookie = $cookies['NAMEOFCOOKIEUNEEDHERE'];
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    echo "</br>Login #:</br>";
        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
          echo $response;
        }


        //---- End -> First Login --- //

        //--- Second GetCameras --- //

$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL =>$server."/ismserver/json/camera/getCameras",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST =>false,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n  \"filter\":{\r\n    \"includeEncoderVideoPortAssociationsOnly\":false,\r\n    \"includeContactClosurePortAssociationsOnly\":false,\r\n    \"byNotInRecommendedFirmwareVersion\":false,\r\n    \"includeSubLocations\":false,\r\n    \"byObjectType\":\"device_vs_camera\",\r\n    \"pageInfo\":{\r\n      \"start\":0,\r\n      \"limit\":100\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/json"
          ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        echo "</br>GetCamerasr #:</br>";
        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
          echo $response;
        }

        //--- End -> GetCameras --- //
```

How can i solve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// save response cookie
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
// send cookie
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You state that "*Server keeps my session and second request works*"

Keep in mind, that the way the server keeps you session, is by sending a cookie with a uniq session ID back to you at your first call to the server.
You have to store this cookie, and send it to the server in all subsequent calls, so the server can know, that it is still *you* it is talking to.
In your code you are saving the cookie at the first call, but you are not resending it at your second call.

All this can be done automaticly with curl by setting `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to the same filename on the client.

`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` tells curl where to store cookies from a call. `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` tells curl where to find cookies, that should bee included in the next call. See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

That way, you don't have to extact the cookie from the header in the response, and you don't have to create your own header when sending the second time.

You don't have to use `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that saves my day :)